# .Net / C# Explanation

Tags: c#, .net, swift

I've been given a part of code to convert it to Swift, but I'm not quite sure that the code is in .net or c# or java.

This is the code

```
public static int calculate(string number) {

    string text = number.ToString();

    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++) {
        int num = Convert.ToInt32((int)(text[text.Length - i - 1] - '0'));
    }

}
```

What I tried is this but I don't have the expected result.

```
func calculate(_ number: String) -> Int {

     let text = number

     for i in 0..<text.count {

         let num = Int(text.substring(text.count - i - 1).trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0"))) ?? 0
     }
}
```

I don't mind to tell me how will it be, I just want to learn what this line of code does so I can convert it to swift

`Int(text.substring(text.count - i - 1).trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0"))) ?? 0`

Also why is he doing this: `string text = number.ToString();`

As the function has a string parameter isn't it the same to put `toString` next to it? (maybe for the code to be more clear? )

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32` is .NET so that solves the first question. There's no reason I can think of to do a `.ToString()` in this case, as it's already a string and there's no formatting being applied.

Comment: ToString here is indeed superfluous. There is no reason.

Comment: Not only what @TJWolschon said, but most Java methods begin with a lower case character, so it would be `number.toString()` not `ToString()`.

Comment: And `string` would be `String` in Java.

Comment: @SebastianHofmann, `string` maps to `String` in .NET too.

Comment: It's also casting to an `int` twice?

Comment: @BabakNaffas but not in Java.

Comment: @TJWolschon yes its very messy I don't see the difference of doing int32 from int

Comment: The `for` loop is completely unnecessary, the entire thing can be written in a single statement... Actually the C# isn't even valid code, it doesn't do anything at all, nor return a value.

Comment: The function does not compile. Not all code paths return a value.

Comment: @RonBeyer there was more code but this line was the one I couldn't understand so I put only this

Comment: `int num` also immediately goes out of scope every iteration of the for-loop, so that's useless...

Comment: lets say it prints it

Comment: So it's essentially trying to flip the string? EDIT: That's exactly what it does. `text = "12345"` becomes `int num = 54321`

Comment: It is an algorithm for barcode scanning, there is no need to stick in what the code does. @TJWolschon and the -‘0’ is like the trimstart?

Comment: I think you first need a source code that compiles successfully.

Comment: Sure there's a *"need to stick in what the code does"*! How else can we decipher *anything* about the C# **or** Swift code? You're not giving up any actual IP here, you're asking for our help to write code we have no idea what the (sloppy) source) code trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know Swift, but I can explain the C# code... It is very convoluted and can be reduced significantly...

Let's start out with the first line:

```
string text = number.ToString();
```

This converts the number to a string, so lets say the number is `123450`, it converts it to `"123450"`. It isn't needed in the example you have because `number` is already passed in as a `string`, so the `.ToString()` can be left off entirely without affecting anything.

Now the `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++) {
    int num = Convert.ToInt32((int)(text[text.Length - i - 1] - '0'));
}
```

It will iterate every character in the string, the loop could be simplified by using the for-loop parameters better:

```
for (int i = text.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    int num = Convert.ToInt32((int)(text[i] - '0'));
}
```

Would have been easier to read, but we'll continue on with the original code...

Ignoring that this really isn't valid in the context above, lets assume you do something with `num` inside the loop to make it worthwhile.

Let's break it down:

```
text[text.Length - i - 1] - '0'
```

Is doing some "ASCII math" to come up with a number. ASCII numbers begin at decimal 48, so `'0'` is equivalent to the value `48`. So for the first iteration:

```
text[text.Length (6) - i (0) - 1 = 5] = '0' - '0' = 0
```

The `Convert.ToInt32` is redundant here because the result of `'0' - '0'` is an integer value of `0`. The cast `(int)` at the front is also redundant, so this entire line can be reduced to:

```
int num = text[text.Length - i - 1] - '0';
```

So that makes a lot more sense. You could write it another way:

```
int num = Convert.ToInt32(text[text.Length - i - 1]) - 48;
```

So it is basically turning the character `'0'` back into the number `0` and so-on with all the numbers 0 through 9. This code will break though (give inaccurate results) if `number` is a floating point value.

---

I know the exercise here is to convert this to another language, but in C# the entire for-loop can be reduced to this:

```
public static int calculate(string number)
{
    var reverseNums = number.ToCharArray().Reverse().Select(c => c - '0').ToList();

    //Do whatever on the reverseNums    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will check it in a while because I just left the office

Comment: note that the OP code actually reverse iterate the string, from end to start (`text[text.Length - i - 1] `)

Comment: @GianPaolo I'm not sure I indicate otherwise, my example gets the last character in the example string, I don't say that it iterates forwards... I will edit that one part to clarify.

Comment: Hi I managed to make it work I just put in my substring to take 1 character at a time, but its working without the need of the trimming (maybe in a different number it would need it) In another algorithm like this I had to add a string like this + "9" and I had to actually add it at the end of my initial string

Comment: So the conclusion is that I had to only take from the last to the first 1 number (as int) at a time to make my calculations but I still can't understand the use of the - '0'  (maybe in swift is just simplier?)

Comment: The `-'0'` converts it from ASCII to the equivalent integer number.

Comment: @mikevorisis, each "item" of a string is a char, not an integer. each char  is (more or less) internally stored as its [ascii code](https://www.asciitable.com/), e.g. '3' is 51, '0' is 48, 'A' is 61. So '3' - '0' is 51-48 = 3: it's a way to get the numeric value of the char in the range '0'-'9'